# How to monitor 100 folders for change

Tags: windows-server-2008

I need to be able to detect when files and folders are copied to a 1 of 100 subfolders  in a file share,  then copy those files/folders onto another site. I currently use powershell for this but it's not a good solution, was hoping someone could give me pointers on alternative for monitoring windows file share
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a .NET application to copy any new file over FTP.
I used [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) Class to fire an event whenever there is a new incoming file. You can enable the watcher to look into sub directories. Then copy those file to your desired location with the help of [File Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx).

ref: msdn